# Specific stocksize{14cm}{21cm} in memoir and shorter margins

Tags: memoir

I have instructions to use the specific size of book 14x21cm so I included the `\setstocksize{21cm}{14cm}` coommand....
The margins also have the specific size of 0,5inches in every direction so the text is placed right in the center of the page...But how do I apply that?

I am using

```
\setulmarginsandblock{0,5in}{0,5in}{*} %Define margem vertical maior
\checkandfixthelayout %Define margem vertical maior

\setlrmarginsandblock{0,5in}{0,5in}{*} %Define margem horizontal maior
\checkandfixthelayout %Define margem horizontal maior`
```

But there's an error right after the \checkandfixthelayout:

> Class memoir Error: \paperwidth (421.10078pt) and/or \trimedge (0.0pt)
>   are too large for \stockwidth (398.33858pt) by 22.7622pt.

Is there any other way to do it?

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openany,showtrims,a5paper]{memoir} %Classe estilo memoir
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} %Traduz doc para português do Brasil
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Reconhece acentuação
\usepackage{ebgaramond} % Define a fonte garamond
\usepackage{leading} %Define espaçamento entre linhas
\usepackage{titlesec} %Centralizar Cap e cabeçalho

\setstocksize{21cm}{14cm}

\setulmarginsandblock{0,5in}{0,5in}{*} %Define margem vertical maior
\checkandfixthelayout %Define margem vertical maior

\setlrmarginsandblock{0,5in}{0,5in}{*} %Define margem horizontal maior
\checkandfixthelayout %Define margem horizontal maior

\makeevenfoot{headings}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeevenhead{headings}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{}

\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\makeevenfoot{chapter}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeevenhead{chapter}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{chapter}{}{}{}

\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\bfseries\huge} %Formata Nº título de Cap
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\small} %Formata "Capítulo X"
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge} %Formata Título de Cap
\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\begin{document} 

    \leading{14,5pt}

    \chapter*{Dedicatória}
        \input{1dedicatoria}
        \newpage

    \chapter*{Agradecimentos}
        \input{2agradecimentos}

    \tableofcontents*

    \chapter*{Síntese}
        \input{3sintese}

    \chapter*{Apresentação}
        \input{4apresentacao}

    \chapter{Preparação}
        \input{5preparacao}
    ...

    \chapter*{Conclusão}
        \input{26conclusao}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not at a pc so cannot test, but you only need one checkandfixthelayout the last one, you might also want to look up in the manual about the various algorithms behind it

Comment: Do you mean `0.5` inches rather than `0,5` ?

Comment: Tried putting some extras \checkandfixthelayout.... did not work.
Commas or final stop are indifferent.
I have added some extra code to the MWE, maybe there is something there causing the error.

Comment: As I said, perhaps start by removing the first checkandfixthelayout, only one is needed. And remove the titlesec package, you're not using it.

Comment: Alright.It still shows error.

Comment: I thought the command /setstocksize alone would do the trick, but it is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of read what I say, you should only have ONE `\checkandfixthelayout`! this is the macro that checks the values.

Sendcondly, plesae always post something we can use, we do not have all the files you include (the `kantlipsum` package can be used for filler text)

Third, why are you changing the stock size from a5paper (210mm by 148mm) to 210mm by 140mm, that seems a bit strange. If you need it, you'll also need to run `\settrimmedsize` in order to translate it into page size (it sets `\paperwidth/height`, if the paper size is the same as the stock, then you can just use `\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}`

This works fine (I've removed everything irrelevant to your question)

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openany,showtrims,a5paper]{memoir} %Classe estilo memoir
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} %Traduz doc para português do Brasil
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Reconhece acentuação
\usepackage{leading} %Define espaçamento entre linhas

\setstocksize{21cm}{14cm}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.5in}{0.5in}{*} %Define margem vertical maior
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.5in}{0.5in}{*} %Define margem horizontal maior
\setheadfoot{0.25in}{0.25in}
\setheaderspaces{*}{*}{0.5}
\checkandfixthelayout %Define margem horizontal maior

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document} 

\leading{14,5pt}

\kant


\end{document}
```

Comment: daleif, thanks for the help, it worked.

I had tried to include only one \checkandfixlayout but it did not work....
I will make sure to add lipsum to substitute the chapters, texts, etc..next time.
The specific stock size is an instruction I received to format the book this way.

I am new to LaTex and to tex.stackexchange...thanks for the help.
I really appreciate this website organization.